# How to export trees to HTML table

Tags: org-mode, org-export, html

Is there a built-in function/feature to export org headlines (not just properties drawers) and associated content into a HTML table?  Can this be done with a custom css and if so, what might the template look like?
Thanks in advance for your pointers.

[image: Updated representation]

Comment: How would the tree get mapped to a table? An (abstract) example of the mapping you'd like to see would help.

Comment: Please read [the short description of the `elisp` tag](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/elisp) before using it. The tag is for questions about the language itself, not for application programming or programming problems.

Comment: A simple 3x3 table could have the following structure and the idea is to extend the table size without restrictions.                                                            
* Row 0 
** R0C0 header
** R0C1 header
** R0C2 header
** R3C0 header

* Row 1 header (for R1C0 cell)
- first list item for R1C1 cell
- second list item for R1C2 cell

* Row 2 header (for R2C0)
- first list item goes to R2C1
- second list item for R2C2
- third list item for R2C3

* Row 3 header (for R3C0)
- first list item goes to R3C1
- second list item for R3C2

Comment: Tobias, sorry for any confusion.  -jay

Comment: @JayIyer No problem. Happens often. I just didn't want to remove the tag without any notice.

Comment: IIUC, we are to assume that there is an arbitrary number of rows, but the number of columns  N is fixed by the number of level-2 headlines in the first level-1 headline, that there are no other level-2 headlines anywhere and that each level-1 headline (other than the first one) contains  a list of exactly N-1 entries (and nothing else)? Anything else is an error. Is that correct?

Comment: Hi NickD, your understanding is correct.  Also, each of the table cells can contain text/number of arbitrary length to support multi-line content.